# Error:Android Pre Dex: Android SDK is not specified

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have downloaded `gdx-setup.jar` from website and I run it as:

`java -jar gdx-setup.jar`

I select the options that I want and generate project for `idea` (libgdx 1.6.2). When I click in generate button, the tool doesn't throw me any error.

When I run `idea 14.1.3` I go to File > Open... and select the ipr file generated.

When I try to run desktop launcher, `idea` throw me the next error:

`Error:Android Pre Dex: [android] Android SDK is not specified`

I have tried with different build tools and API of android (most of them throw me warnings when I pressed generate button from `gdx-setup.jar`). I am using Build tools 20.0.0 and API 20 and with this configuration `gdx-setup.jar` doesn't throw me warnings.

I check local.properties of general project:
`sdk.dir=/home/XXXX/Escritorio/android-sdk-linux-libgdx/`
it is right
I check File > project structure... > SDK's > Android SDK and it is also right:
`/home/XXXX/Escritorio/android-sdk-linux-libgdx`

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go in Project Structure, select Platform Settings -> SDKs (left panel) then add your Android SDK by selecting the +. Then in Project Settings -> Module , choose the android module, and choose the android SDK that you just added.