# Android Pre-Dex: Android SDK is not specified without android SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I get this error in IDEA, but I don't want to use an Android SDK. I've been able to build and run just fine before, and one day I just opened my project like I usually do, and I started getting this error.

I'm working on a game with libgdx, and I've taken out all android dependencies (in the settings and build files). It has worked just fine before, how do I stop this error from happening?

Also, I can do ./gradlew desktop:build and ./gradlew desktop:run and everything works fine. So I'm guessing it's an IDEA thing...

Edit: In the suggested duplicate, the solution is to add a reference to the Android SDK. I don't want to use the Android SDK, so I can't use the solution on the suggested duplicate.

Comment: It's hard to say what's the problem without looking at some sample project.

Comment: What would be sufficient to show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Android Pre Dex: Android SDK is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821256/errorandroid-pre-dex-android-sdk-is-not-specified)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I don't want to use the Android SDK. The solution in the link provided uses an Android SDK to solve the issue.

Comment: @Luca [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured it out.

This was an IDEA problem, not a gradlew or LibGDX problem.

If someone wants to use LibGDX but without the Android SDK you need to do the following:

1. Remove 'android' from settings.gradle
2. Remove the android macro in the build.gradle
3. If you get the 'Android Pre Dex' error when trying to run in IDEA, you need to remove all Android references. It was under Project Structure -> Modules, one of the Modules will have an Android reference. Delete it, and you should be good to go!